# Bug on select with count and case

Tags: h2

I have a test which uses H2 as an in memory database. The following table, data and query produces a single row in MySQL with the expected values, but not in H2:

```
CREATE TABLE redirects (
  site_id    INTEGER NOT NULL,
  company_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  type       CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  capture    TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO redirects (site_id, company_id, type, capture) VALUES (1, 1, 'm', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO redirects (site_id, company_id, type, capture) VALUES (1, 2, 'm', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO redirects (site_id, company_id, type, capture) VALUES (1, 1, 'h', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO redirects (site_id, company_id, type, capture) VALUES (1, 1, 'h', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO redirects (site_id, company_id, type, capture) VALUES (1, 2, 'h', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO redirects (site_id, company_id, type, capture) VALUES (1, 1, 'a', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO redirects (site_id, company_id, type, capture) VALUES (1, 1, 'a', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO redirects (site_id, company_id, type, capture) VALUES (1, 1, 'a', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO redirects (site_id, company_id, type, capture) VALUES (1, 2, 'a', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

SELECT
    COALESCE(site_id, 1) site_id,
    COALESCE(company_id, -1) company_id,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'm' THEN 1 END) views,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN type IN ('h', 'a') THEN 1 END) clicks
FROM 
    redirects
WHERE 
    (site_id = 1 AND company_id = 3 AND capture > TIMESTAMP '2017-04-24 00:00:00.0');
```

The result in MySQL is the following:

```
+---------+------------+-------+--------+
| site_id | company_id | views | clicks |
+---------+------------+-------+--------+
|       1 |         -1 |     0 |      0 |
+---------+------------+-------+--------+
```

However, in H2 (version 1.4.194) the result is:

```
SITE_ID     COMPANY_ID      VIEWS   CLICKS  
1           2               0       0
```

Comment: are you sure about `AND company_id = 3 `?

Comment: Yes, the test is supposed to check that the "default" row is returned for a company ID that does not have any redirects. This is required by the API that sits on top of this SQL.